# Click handler not working in chrome, but working in FF and I.E

Tags: jquery, magento, google-chrome, filter

This jQuery code in magento is basically a three step auto part finder, where first user selects year of manufacturing, then the manufacturing company and then the model number to get the auto parts lists. The code just rocks on IE and Firefox but does not work on Chrome. I am not able to find my error. Looking forward for a solution

```
$j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function(){
    for(st1 = 1; st1 <= 1000; st1++) {
        //filling options of select.opt1
        //works fine
    }

    $j("#shop-by-vehicle select.opt1 option").click(function() {
        $j("#shop-by-vehicle select.opt2 option").remove();
        $j("#shop-by-vehicle select.opt3 option").remove();
        for(st2 = 1; st2 <= 1000; st2++) {
            //used to fill options of select.opt2
        }

        $j("#shop-by-vehicle select.opt2 option").click(function() {
            $j("#shop-by-vehicle select.opt3 option").remove();
            for(st3 = 1; st3 <= 10000; st3++) {
                //used to fill options of select.opt3
            }

            $j("#shop-by-vehicle select.opt3 option").click(function() {
                // do something when select.opt3 options are clicked
            });
        });
    });
}); //end jquery function
```

HTML CODE

```
<div id="shop-by-vehicle">
    <div class="steps">
        <select class="opt1 opt"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="steps">
        <select class="opt2 opt"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="steps">
        <select class="opt3 opt"></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: does $j=jQuery.noConflict(); return jQuery?

Comment: also, have you tried to wrap your code in an anonymous closure rather than using noconflict? maybe thats the issue

Comment: Don't bind click events to the options. Instead, bind change events to the selects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested `click` handlers are very rarely the correct solution to a problem. Also, use the `change` event on `select` elements for full accessibility. Try this:

```
$j(document).ready(function(){
    for(st1 = 1; st1 <= 1000; st1++) {
        //filling options of select.opt1
        //works fine
    }

    $j("#shop-by-vehicle select.opt1").change(function() {
        $j("#shop-by-vehicle select.opt2").empty();
        $j("#shop-by-vehicle select.opt3").empty();
        for(st2 = 1; st2 <= 1000; st2++) {
            //used to fill options of select.opt2
        }
    });


    $j("#shop-by-vehicle select.opt2").change(function() {
        $j("#shop-by-vehicle select.opt3").empty();
        for(st3 = 1; st3 <= 10000; st3++) {
            //used to fill options of select.opt3
        }
    });


    $j("#shop-by-vehicle select.opt3").change(function() {
        // do something when select.opt3 options are clicked
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on) for dynamic elements as your are `removing` and `adding options`

Use

```
 $("#shop-by-vehicle select.opt2").on('click','option',function(){
```

in place of

```
("#shop-by-vehicle select.opt2 option").click(function(){
```

like,

```
;(function($){
    // you can use $ in place of $j now
    $(document).ready(function(){
        for(st1=1;st1<=1000;st1++)
        {
            //filling options of select.opt1
            //works fine
        }
        $("#shop-by-vehicle select.opt1 option").click(function()
        {

            $("#shop-by-vehicle select.opt2 option").remove();
            $("#shop-by-vehicle select.opt3 option").remove();
            for(st2=1;st2<=1000;st2++)
            {
                //used to fill options of select.opt2
            }

            // use on() for dynamic elements
            $("#shop-by-vehicle select.opt2").on('click','option',function(){
                $("#shop-by-vehicle select.opt3 option").remove();
                for(st3=1;st3<=10000;st3++)
                {
                     //used to fill options of select.opt3
                }
                // use on() for dynamic elements
                $("#shop-by-vehicle select.opt3").on('click','option',function()
                {
                    // do something when select.opt3 options are clicked
                });
            });
        });
    });//end jquery function
})(window.jQuery);// pass jQuery here
```